# consulta mysql con varios filtros

Tags: mysql, sql

Tengo este query en MySQL y quisiera saber si es posible hacer con este query las siguientes consulta:

1. al menos por el rango de fecha
2. por una fecha de inicio sin suministrar la fecha final
3. solo por el nombre, apellido, id_personal o por iteractions.title
4. filtrar por nombre y iteractions.title agregando o no un rango de
   fecha

Nota: este query es a modo de ejemplo ya que no he podido dar con uno que me haga todas las tareas que quiero y puede que este tenga algunos errores.

```
SELECT  title,
        result, 
        first_name,
        last_name,
        id_personal,
        iteractions.create_date as create_date, 
        iteractions.id as id_iteraction,
        clients_profile.id as id_client_profile 
FROM 
        clients_profile left join iteractions on clients_profile.id = iteractions.id_client_profile 
WHERE 
        first_name = 'delvin' OR
        last_name = '' OR
        id_personal = '' OR
        iteractions.title= '' OR
        iteractions.create_date BETWEEN '2017-10-23 00:00:00' AND  '2017-10-23 23:59:59';
```

Comment: Necesitamos saber con que gestionas la consulta, es decir, no es compatible el punto 1 con el punto 2 (se contradicen, en uno necesitas rango de fechas (es decir `fecha-inicio` y `fecha-fin`),mientras que en el otro necesitas que solo se ponga `fecha-inicio`. ¿Cómo identificamos que tipo de consulta se va a hacer?. Se pueden hacer todas por separado, pero para hacerlas 'juntas' necesitamos que sean compatibles, a no ser claro, que quieras en caso de que este especificada `fecha-inicio` y `fecha-fin` realizar el punto 1, si solo está `fecha-inicio` realizar el punto 2.

Comment: Gracias por la ayuda.

Comment: Por ejemplo: puede que en una consulta el usuario solo envíe el nombre y el rango de fecha o mande solo el nombre lo que busco lograr es que mi query filtre con los parámetros que se le envíen sean todos a la vez o solo 1. Gracias anticipadas por ayuda

Comment: ¿Usarás PDO o mysqli?

Comment: actualmente uso PDO